# Rails 3.1.10 upgrade results in consistent [GET /] miss

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes, upgrade

After upgrading an application from Rails `3.0.20` to Rails `3.1.10`, I'm finding some trouble in rendering any of my routes; All requests result in a empty body with a status of "Success 200", but the rails log reports:

`cache: [GET /route] miss`

I get the same results even after clearing the rails cache.

I'm currently debugging the `ApplicationController` and subsequent controllers in aims of finding out where the response goes wrong.

Any pointer in further debugging would  much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as though `query_reviewer` was the source of this issue.

After a quick `git stash` and `bundle update`, I found that a few gems had been updated, namely `query_reviewer`, from `0.1.6` to `0.1.7`.  It seems that the outstanding changes between those versions caused some regressions, namely the one described in my question.

Solution: reverting `query_reviewer` from `0.1.7` to `0.1.6`.